# Replayer freezes the entire webpage

Tags: bug, pgn-viewer

```
[fen ""]

1.  g4 f5 2.  gxf5 g5 3.  h4 g4 4.  h5 Kf7 5.  f6 Ke6 6.  fxe7 Kf6 7.  e8=Q g3 8.  Nf3 g2 9.  Rh4 g1=B 10.  a4 b5 11.  axb5 a6 12.  bxa6 Bb7 13.  axb7 Nc6 14.  bxa8=Q Qe7 15.  Qeb8 Qd6 16.  e4 Kg7 17.  e5 Qd5 18.  e6 Qe5+ 19.  Qe2 Qf6 20.  exd7 Qf7 21.  d8=Q Nce7 22.  Qdxc7 Nf6 23.  Qea6 Nfd5 24.  Qac8 Nf6 25.  Ne5 Ned5 26.  f4 Kg8 27.  Nc6 Ng4 28.  c4 Ne5 29.  fxe5 Qf6 30.  e6 Qf7 31.  e7 Qf6 32.  e8=Q Qf7 33.  Nd4 Qe7+ 34.  Kd1 Qf7 35.  Qea4 Qg7 36.  Q4a7 Qf7 37.  c5 Qe6 38.  Qd6 Qe7 39.  c6 Qf7 40.  c7 Qe7 41.  Qcb7 Qf7 42.  c8=Q Qe7 43.  Qdc7 Qf7 44.  Nf5 Nf6 45.  d4 Ne4 46.  d5 Bc5 47.  Ne7+ Kg7 48.  Bg5 Qg6 49.  Nc6+ Qf7 50.  Bd8 Nf6 51.  Re4 Nd7 52.  Re7 Kg8 53.  Rxd7 Kg7 54.  Ne7 Bb4 55.  Ra6 Ba3 56.  Rb6 Bc5 57.  Ba6 Ba3 58.  b4 Bb2 59.  b5 Ba3 60.  Nd2 Bb4 61.  Nb3 Qe6 62.  h6+ Kf7 63.  Kc2 Rg8 64.  Kd3 Rg7 65.  hxg7 Kf6 66.  g8=Q Ba3 67.  Qg1 h5 68.  Qgc5 h4 69.  Q5c6 Kf7 70.  Kd4 Qh6 71.  Nc5 Qf4+ 72.  Qxf4+ Kg7 73.  Qfd6 h3 74.  Qf4 h2 75.  Qxh2 Kf7 76.  Qhc7 Kg7 77.  Ke5 Kf7 78.  Kd6 Kf6 (1/2, 1/2).
```

The above replayer, from [Open problems in chess involving maximum material imbalances](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/40873/19465), works fine up to `46.d5`. If you try to advance it beyond that, to `46...Bc5`, the entire webpage freezes up. I tested this in both Firefox and Chrome, on both macOS and Linux.

Answer (score 4):

There's a bug because the bishop on f8 is pinned so the replayer can't figure out the legal move.  I think this is fixed in a later version, but I'll confirm whether or not that's the case.